# How to import my project into Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a project and I want to import it into Xamarin Studio, but I can't find a way to do that.

When using eclipse, I can open a file named `**.project`, what's the equivalent when I want import it into my Xamarin Studio?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand - are you trying to import eclipse project into xamarin studio? Eclipse is a Java IDE that has no native support for C# (only through plugins). Then I can assume that your original project is in Java and there is no way for you to import it into xamarin

Comment: no i'am trying to import an xamarin android project , I don't found the "import" option in the xamarin studio like the" import" option in the eclipse editor ( i say eclipse just for instance no more ). my project just contain files.cs , i wanna to run it in my xamarin studio to generate the apk . But I 'don't find the way to import it .that's it

Comment: I'm not an expert in Xamarin but it should be based on Visual studio and there should be a solution file which works as a project file in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

It's not import xamarne studio .  Because your project Java , Xamarine C# .

Comment: No my project is just Xamarin android with c#